# Saving/Exporting All Artboards, Including Names, to Single File

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to save (or export) all Artboards into a single file - jpg or pdf, doesn't matter. That's easy enough but the catch is, I need to also include each individual artboard's name with the asset like a label. I feel like this has got to be pretty easy and I'm just over looking something, but I can't figure it out :/

(An example would be, let's say I'm designing banner ads or site comps - I would need to see each layout side by side, along with the corresponding name so I know what I'm looking out outside of Photoshop.)

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You simply have all the layers names accordingly then right click on the layer you want to export.

[image]

Make sure the name is correct and then click Export All...

[image]

And save to the location you need it to be in.

[image]